# Give CPU more power to plot in Octave

Tags: plot, cpu, gnuplot, octave, time-complexity

I made this function in Octave which plots fractals. Now, it takes a long time to plot all the points I've calculated. I've made my function as efficient as possible, the only way I think I can make it plot faster is by having my CPU completely focus itself on the function or telling it somehow it should focus on my plot.

Is there a way I can do this or is this really the limit?

Answer (score 2):

To determine how much CPU is being consumed for your plot, run your plot, and in a separate window (assuming your on Linux/Unix), run the `top` command. (for windows, launch the task master and switch to the 'Processes' tab, click on CPU header to sort by CPU).

(The rollover description for Octave on the tag on your question says that Octave is a scripting language. I would expect it's calling `gnuplot` to create the plots. Look for this as the highest CPU consumer).

You should see that your Octave/gnuplot cmd is near the top of the list, and for `top` there is a column labeled `%CPU` (or similar). This will show you how much CPU that process is consuming.

I would expect to see that process is consuming 95% or more CPU. If you see that is a significantly lower number, then you need to check the processes below that, are they consuming the remaining CPU (some sort of Virus scan (on a PC), or DB or Server?)?  If a competing program is the problem, then you'll have to decide if you can wait til it/they are finished, OR that you can kill them and restart later. (For lunix, use `kill -15 pid` or `kill -11 pid`. Only use `kill -9 pid` as a last resort. Search here for articles on correct order for trying to `kill -$n`)

If there are no competing processes AND it `octave/gnuplot` is using less than 95%, then you'll have to find alternate tools to see what is holding up the process. (This is unlikely, it's possible some part of your overall plotting process is either Disk I/O or Network I/O bound).

So, it depends on the timescale you're currently experiencing versus the time you "want" to experience.

Does your system have multiple CPUs? Then you'll need to study the `octave/gnuplot` documentation to see if  it supports a switch to indicate "use $n available CPUs for processing". (Or find a plotting program that does support using $n multiple CPUs).

Realistically, if your process now takes 10 mins, and you can, by eliminating competing processes, go from 60% to 90%, that is a %50 increase in CPU, but will only reduce it to 5 mins (not certain, maybe less, math is **not** my strong point ;-)). Being able to divide the task over 5-10-?? CPUs will be the most certain path to faster turn-around times.

So, to go further with this, you'll need to edit your question with some data points. How long is your plot taking? How big is the file it's processing. Is there something especially math intensive for the plotting you're doing? Could a pre-processed data file speed up the calcs? Also, if the results of `top` don't show gnuplot running at 99% CPU, then edit your posting to show the `top` output that will help us understand your problem. (Paste in your `top` output, select it with your mouse, and then use the formatting tool `{}` at the top of the input box to keep the formatting and avoid having the output wrap in your posting).

IHTH.

P.S. Note the # of followers for each of the tags you've assigned to your question by rolling over. You might get more useful "eyes" on your question by including a tag for the OS you're using, and a tag related to performance measurement/testing (Go to the tags tab and type in various terms to see how many followers you're getting. One bit of S.O. etiquette is to only specify 1 programming language (if appropriate) and that may apply to OS's too.)